# ServiceStack - Elmah how to test its status?

Tags: servicestack, elmah

I have configured Elmah in ServiceStack. No error from build, but get 404 when I put elmah.axd in. The endpoint are

```
http://localhost:9384/api/elmah.axd

http://localhost:9384/elmah.axd
```

So dose it indicate an unsuccessful installation or how else can I test it? Thanks.

EDIT: Hi, I was following the document on ServiceStack site so here it goes:

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            LogManager.LogFactory = new ElmahLogFactory(new ConsoleLogFactory(), this);
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
```

...

```
<handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
           type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      </modules>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look properly configured, please include the releavant parts in your Web.config where you've registered the Elmah http modules and elmah configuration.

Comment: @mythz, thank you. I have updated the post. Could you please kindly have a look? Thanks.